# How to "merge" Core Data configurations?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Core Data with `MagicalRecord`, my model has two configurations:

[image]

PrefilledConfiguration has four entities, UserDataConfigurations has six. Now I would like to merge them all in the default configuration - what's the best way to achieve that?

Is there a migration necessary? How can I transfer all existing data into the new, merged (default?) configuration?

Comment: Do your entities appear in multiple configurations?

Comment: each entity is either in PrefilledConfiguration or in UserDataConfiguration; none of them in both

Comment: I tried a similar thing a while ago and failed. After successfully merging in some changes, the update path from an older version was completely broken. It did not give any error, but all user data was gone.  
I guess you will have to do it by hand and yes you will need an update script to migrate the data.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try edit you xcdatamodel file manually. Inside the package it is simple XML file. This is example from the my test xcdatamodel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="" type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="7701" systemVersion="14D136" minimumToolsVersion="Automatic" macOSVersion="Automatic" iOSVersion="Automatic">
    <entity name="Entity" isAbstract="YES" syncable="YES"/>
    <entity name="Event">
        <attribute name="timeStamp" optional="YES" attributeType="Date">
            <userInfo/>
        </attribute>
        <userInfo/>
    </entity>
    <configuration name="Test"/>
    <elements>
        <element name="Event" positionX="261" positionY="189" width="128" height="60"/>
        <element name="Entity" positionX="261" positionY="198" width="128" height="45"/>
    </elements>
</model>
```